# Extra right insterted appears in array

Tags: pdftex

in the given tex prepared by MATHEMATICA, I get an error when writing it in an array:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
    B_n=-\frac{1}{3} i^{-n} \left(2.25 \left(J_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)-J_{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right) Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+6 J_n\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) \left(\frac{3}{2} Y_{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\\n Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\right) (J_n(1) H_{n-1}^{(1)}(1)-J_{n-1}(1) H_n^{(1)}(1))
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

where the erorr message is:

```
"Missing .\right inserted
Extra .\right"
```

If I insert an extra .\right it does not go away. So where is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot break a `\left ... \right` across lines.

Comment: Note that more or less all the `\left...\right` constructions in this example are irrelevant.

Comment: @daleif: sorry about that. Not enough coffee before commenting is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

First of you cannot break `\left...\right` across a line break. Secondly I do not see the point in using `array` here.

Here is my suggestion

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    B_n=-\frac{1}{3} i^{-n} \biggl[
    & 2.25 \Bigl\{
    J_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) -J_{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)
    \Bigr\} Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)
    \\
    &+6J_n\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)
    \Bigl\{ \frac{3}{2} Y_{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) -n
    Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \Bigr\} \biggr]
    \\
    &\cdot\bigl[ J_n(1)
    H_{n-1}^{(1)}(1) -J_{n-1}(1)H_n^{(1)}(1) \bigr]
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the outmost \right( and \left) to \bigg( and \bigg)

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
    B_n=-\frac{1}{3} i^{-n} \bigg(2.25 \left(J_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)-J_{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\right) Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\\+6 J_n\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) \left(\frac{3}{2} Y_{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\\n Y_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\bigg) (J_n(1) H_{n-1}^{(1)}(1)-J_{n-1}(1) H_n^{(1)}(1))
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

That fixes the problem